# How can I uninstall all pop-up in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, popup-ads

Hi I Notice that I have installed some strange pop-up when I open chrome and firefox, someone know how to remove them, maybe quick from terminal?

Comment: We don't know your release of Ubuntu, which is basic knowledge. It's likely the pop-ups aren't coming from your Ubuntu system, but add-ons you've added to your browser that are running in the background (ie. you can give permission for them to be run in the background within the browser).... ie. I'd look first in what you've added to your browser and remove them there.  Terminal commands are geared at changing Ubuntu, but your issue is likely within the browser itself.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem

Comment: @guiverc I have tried to stop them from the browser by removing the permission but this is not working.

Comment: I don't know your OS & release as I already stated; so I don't know what type of packages you are using (*thus commands you can use to assist you*). You've also not provided any specifics; ie. a link to where we can see the pop-up (ie. clarity as Bruni suggested your question needed) so currently we'd only be guessing as we have too limited detail to provide specific help.